# Potential proof that convolution over $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ is compact?

Tags: functional-analysis

In class we've shown that the matrix representation of:

$$Cf:L^2[-\pi,\pi] \to L^2[-\pi,\pi]$$
$$ (C_fg)(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)g(x-t)dt$$

denoted $[C_f]$, is diagonal with $[C_f]_{n,n}=\hat{f}(n)$ (where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$).

We also proved the following two statements for:

$$T:\ell_2\to \ell_2$$
$$ T(a_1,a_2,\dots)=(w_1a_1, w_2a_2,\dots) $$

1. It is a bounded and well-defined operator when $(w_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, in which case: $||T||=||w||_{\infty}$.
2. It is compact when $w_i \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

With these two results, would it be correct to say that $C_f$ is compact since $\hat{f}(n) \to 0$? If so - why aren't we bothered by the double-sided infinity? If not - where is my reasoning wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: If $f\in L^1(-\pi,\pi)$ the operator is compact, as $\widehat{f}(n)\to 0$ when $|n|\to \infty.$ The double sides infinity is not an obstacle, as the corresponding operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ is compact